# Laravel compact multiple data to become single data and sum 1 column

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, eloquent

Hello i have multiple data from salesItem table, data could be return like this

[Data Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHgv7.png)

and how could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ELOQUENT ORM` you can try like this:

```
$dataArray = SalesItem::select("*",sum(QTY) as totQuantity)
->grouby('variant_id')
->get()
->toArray();
```

Assumption: You have already defined the Modal file for `SalesItem`.